# Funnel plot and regtest in R

Tags: r

I am learning meta analysis in R. I would like to compute regtest from metafor library. See example of my data:

```
library("metafor")

value <- c(0.0001,0.0003,0.0002,0.0009,0.01,0.002)
se <- c(1,3,2,4,0,3)
data <- data.frame(value, se)

regtest(x = data$value, sei = data$se, model="rma")
```

But I got an error `Error in rma.uni(yi, vi, mods = X, intercept = FALSE, ...) :  Division by zero when computing the inverse variance weights. In addition: Warning message: There are outcomes with non-positive sampling variances.`

It seems that values are too small, but how can I fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont't divide by zero anymore ;)

```
value <- c(0.0001,0.0003,0.0002,0.0009,0.01,0.002)
se <- c(1,3,2,4,1,3)
data <- data.frame(value, se)

regtest(x = data$value, sei = data$se, model="rma")
```

---

```
Regression Test for Funnel Plot Asymmetry

Model:     mixed-effects meta-regression model
Predictor: standard error

Test for Funnel Plot Asymmetry: z = -0.0025, p = 0.9980
Limit Estimate (as sei -> 0):   b = 0.0069 (CI: -2.5466, 2.5605)
```